# Calculating BIC manually for lm object

Tags: r, lm

I can't quite figure out why I'm having trouble calculating the Bayesian Information Criterion correctly, and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I am doing this because I am trying to calculate the BIC manually (for `plm` objects, which don't seem to have an established routine associated with them). I took the formula from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), which gives the formula for the BIC in terms of the Residual Sum of Squares, rather than the Log Likelihood.

```
y<-rnorm(100)
x<-rnorm(100)
m.test<-lm(y ~ x) 

n<-100 
rss<-sum(m.test$residuals^2) 
k<-3 
bic.mine<-n*log(rss/n)+k*log(n) #formula from wikipedia
bic.stats<-BIC(m.test) #using stats package
abs(bic.mine-bic.stats) #mine is off!
```

Running the code a bunch of times, I realize that the difference between the BIC I obtain and the BIC obtained from the stats package is constant, so my suspicion is that I'm missing some kind of scaling factor. Is that right? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Thanks for all the comments. I tried to implement the suggestions and post an answer, but I'm still off by a constant. Revised code below.

```
y<-rnorm(100)
x<-rnorm(100)
m.test<-lm(y ~ x) 

n<-100
res<-m.test$residuals
rss<-sum(res^2) 
k<-3; df<-n-k; w<-rep(1,N) #params, dfs, weights
ll<-0.5 * (sum(log(w)) - n *
             (log(2 * pi) + 1 - log(n) + log(sum(w * res^2))))
ll.stats<-logLik(m.test)
abs(ll.stats-ll)==0 #same, prob is not here

bic.mine<-n*log(rss/n)+k*log(n) #formula from wikipedia
bic.exact<- -2 * ll + log(n) * df #suggestions from comments
bic.stats<-BIC(m.test) #using stats package
abs(bic.mine-bic.stats) #mine was off
abs(bic.exact-bic.stats) #this is still off, though
```

Comment: Heh, I like this question :) I think the most straightforward way is to look at the source code of `BIC`. With `methods(BIC)` you can see that there are two methods. I presume `BIC.default` gets called, but if you type `BIC.default` you'll get an error. Use `stats:::BIC.default` instead to see the source code. Here you can see exactly how the BIC is calculated and compare with your own script. I hope this helps at least a little bit.

Comment: @Laterow in general use `getAnywhere("BIC.default")` in case you don't know the package

Comment: from `?BIC` "BIC is defined as `AIC(object, ..., k = log(nobs(object)))`"; as to AIC, a citation is given for Sakamoto, Ishiguro and Kitagawa's _Akaike Imformation Criterion Statistics_

Comment: And in `BIC.default` we find the formula: `-2 * as.numeric(lls) + log(nos) * attr(lls, "df")`, with `lls` the log likelihood of the object, `nos` the number of observations, and `df` the degrees of freedom.

Comment: again using `getAnywhere` to find `logLik.lm`, we see `lls` is given by `0.5 * (sum(log(w)) - N * (log(2 * pi) + 1 - log(N) + 
        log(sum(w * res^2))))`; given you've done unweighted OLS, `w <- rep(1, N)`. `res` is the vector of residuals.

Comment: The formula you are using does not give the exact value of the BIC, but only "up to an additive constant, which depends only on n and not on the model" (see the wikipedia page you linked to). The exact value of the BIC is given by -2*logLmax + 3 * log(100) and the maximum log likelihood value for your problem is given by the formula @MichaelChirico provided in his comments (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood for more details)

Comment: someone (possibly the OP) should assemble an answer from all of these comments ...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did my best, but couldn't make an answer work.. Can anyone spot what's off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to help from the commenters, here's the answer:

```
y<-rnorm(100)
x<-rnorm(100)
m<-lm(y ~ x)
```

To get the `BIC` or `AIC`, you first need the associated log likelihood.

Calculating the log likelihood requires a vector of residuals, the number of observations in the data, and a vector of weights (if applicable)

```
res<-m$residuals
n<-nrow(m$model)    
w<-rep(1,n) #not applicable

ll<-0.5 * (sum(log(w)) - n * (log(2 * pi) + 1 - log(n) + log(sum(w * res^2))))
ll-logLik(m)==0 #TRUE
```

Calculating the `BIC` or `AIC` requires `ll`, and additionally requires the `df` associated with the calculation of the log likelihood, which is equal to the original number of parameters being estimated plus 1.

```
k.original<-length(m$coefficients)
df.ll<-k.original+1 
bic<- -2 * ll + log(n) * df.ll
bic-BIC(m)==0 #TRUE
aic<- -2 * ll + 2 * df.ll
aic-AIC(m)==0 #TRUE
```

Comment: `fit$rank` does not exist for `plm` methods. I suggest using `length(m$coefficients)` instead.